# Is my PC less secure, by enabling XP Firewall - File and Printer Sharing exception?

Tags: windows-xp, security, firewall, file-sharing

I have 2 XP machines sitting behind a router (and it's firewall). I want to share files between them. I've shared C:\ but found the XP firewall was blocking access. I enabled the File and Printer Sharing exception in the firewall and I can access my files.

I realise the XP firewall doesn't block outbound connections and that it isn't really needed due to the firewall in the router, but my question is:

**By enabling the File and Printer Sharing exception, is the PC (doing the sharing) less secure (disregarding the router firewall) than it would be? If so, by how much?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, technicaly it would be "less secure" because you have opened up one more service on windows. This is another entry point for a security breach as you have allowed file sharing.

I would not worry about this though if you are behind a router with a firewall on a home connection.  File sharing is a very common use of your personal network. The chances of something happening are not impossible, but are most likely not going to happen with your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but negligibly so for users on home networks.

I might worry about it a little more if this is for a laptop that you often use in crowded public places.